# How to call ASMX (SOAP) Web Services with Swift

Tags: swift

All,

I am brand new to Swift and am loving it!  I want to understand how to better call ASMX (or SOAP) web services.  I see this same example all over the internet, but I know there HAS to be a better way, can anyone lead me to a better tutorial, or better example?

I want to simply get a custom class (or a tuple as a response) from a string (as the request).

Here is a link to the code that I see everywhere, please help me with an easer solution:
http://webindream.com/soap-with-swift/

Bill

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need this https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine. It's written in Objective-C. Lucky that it's not too difficult to use OC libraries in Swift.

For more infos on calling OC code in Swift, check out this question [How to call Objective C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift?rq=1)

Comment: Still looking for more examples.  This is okay, but its not the answer I am looking for.  This didn't work for me either in my example.  Do you know of any other examples?

Comment: This libraray is not working for you? In which way is it not working?